# Uncaught ReferenceError: [function] is not defined in Jsp using c:forEach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Im developing a webapplication which uses struts,when i try the code on my system which im currently developing,then its working fine but when i deploy it on live server its not calling the Javascript function which also uses c:forEach inside it.
I dont know what i am doing wrong,i do know that theres a lot of questions regarding this but i tried everything and none of them works for my scenario.This is my Jsp file.

```
<body>
<logic:equal name="menu" value="package">
                                    <h2><span>Packages</span></h2>
                                    <span class="dropdown place">
                                        <a class="dd_btn" href="javascript:void(0);" >Action</a>
                                        <ul class="subdrop">
                                            <li><a onclick="display('addPackDiv')" href="javascript:void(0);">Create New</a></li>
                                            <li><a onclick="setPackage();" href="javascript:void(0);">Edit</a></li>
                                            <li><a onclick="return delPackage();" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a></li>
                                            <li><a onclick="return exportPackages();" href="javascript:void(0);">Export</a></li>
                                            <li><a onclick="return featurePackages('feature');" href="javascript:void(0);">Feature</a></li>
                                            <li><a onclick="return featurePackages('unfeature');" href="javascript:void(0);">UnFeature</a></li>

                                        </ul>
                                    </span>
                                </logic:equal>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setPackage(){
                alert("in setpackage");
                var ids = "";
                var chbxs = document.forms[0].actionCheckBox;
                if (chbxs.length != undefined) {
                    for (i = 0; i < chbxs.length; i++)
                    {
                        if (chbxs[i].type == 'checkbox' && chbxs[i].checked)
                        {
                            var cname = chbxs[i].value;
                            if (!cname)
                                continue;
                            if (ids == "")
                                ids = cname;
                            else
                                ids += "," + cname + "";

                        }
                    }

                    if (ids == null || ids == "") {
                        jAlert("Please select one item to edit");
                        return;
                    }

                    if (ids.split(",").length > 1) {
                        jAlert("Select only one item to edit.");
                        return;
                    }
                } else {  //If Not Node List.
                    try {
                        ids = chbxs.value;
                    } catch (err) {
                    }
                }

                //alert("step 1 "+ids);
            /* collection reset */
                document.getElementById('updateCollection').innerHTML = '';
                var updateCollectionSel = document.getElementById('updateCollectionSel');
                updateCollectionSel.innerHTML = '';
                var innCollectionHtml = '';
         <c:forEach var="CollectionDTO" items="${requestScope.allCollectionList}">
          innCollectionHtml += "<option value='${CollectionDTO.collectionId}'>${CollectionDTO.collectionName}</option>";
        </c:forEach>
            updateCollectionSel.innerHTML = innCollectionHtml;
            //alert("innCollectionHtml "+innCollectionHtml);

                //END

              //alert("step 2");
              /* program reset */
                document.getElementById('updateProgram').innerHTML = '';
                var updateProgramSel = document.getElementById('updateProgramSel');
                updateProgramSel.innerHTML = '';
                var innProHtml ='';
               <c:forEach var="ProgramDTO" items="${requestScope.allProgramList}">
                innProHtml += "<option value='${ProgramDTO.programid}'>${ProgramDTO.name}</option>";
               </c:forEach>
                 updateProgramSel.innerHTML =   innProHtml; 
                 //alert("innProHtml "+innProHtml);
                //END

                // alert("step 3");

                /* channel reset */
                document.getElementById('updateChannel').innerHTML = '';
                var updateChannelSel = document.getElementById('updateChannelSel');
                updateChannelSel.innerHTML = '';
                var innChannelHtml = '';
        <c:forEach var="SMSChannelDTO" items="${requestScope.allChannelList}">
           innChannelHtml += "<option value='${SMSChannelDTO.channelId}'>${SMSChannelDTO.name}</option>";
        </c:forEach>
            updateChannelSel.innerHTML = innChannelHtml;
             //alert("innChannelHtml "+innChannelHtml);

                //END

               //alert("step 4");
                 var packageId = ids;
                var server = '<%= request.getServerName()%>';
                if (server == 'localhost') {
                    server = server + ":" + '<%= request.getServerPort()%>';
                }
                       <c:forEach var="packageDTO" items="${requestScope.packageList}">
                    if (packageId == '${packageDTO.packageId}') {

                         <c:forEach var="DistributorDTO" items="${requestScope.displayDistributor}">
                         var allDistName1=  '${DistributorDTO.email_id}';
                             document.getElementById(allDistName1).checked = false;
                              document.getElementById("prepaidprice"+allDistName1).value='0.0';
                              document.getElementById("postpaidprice"+allDistName1).value='0.0';
                     </c:forEach>

                        document.getElementById('updatePackageName').value = '${packageDTO.name}';
                        document.getElementById('updatePackageImg1').value = '${packageDTO.image}'
                        document.getElementById('updatefeaturedImage').value = '${packageDTO.featuredImage}';
            <%--document.getElementById('packImg').src = 'http://'+server+'/SMS/'+'${packageDTO.image}';--%>
                        /* refill remaining channel list */
                        var packagesChannelIdArr = new Array(${fn:length(packageDTO.channelList)});
                        var i = 0;
                        <c:forEach var="SMSChannelDTO" items="${packageDTO.channelList}">
                            packagesChannelIdArr[i] = '${SMSChannelDTO.channelId}';
                            i++;
            </c:forEach>
                        setChannels(packagesChannelIdArr);
                        //END

                        /* refill remaining program list */
                        var packagesEventIdArr = new Array(${fn:length(packageDTO.programList)});
                        var j = 0;
                <c:forEach var="ProgramDTO" items="${packageDTO.programList}">
                            packagesEventIdArr[j] = '${ProgramDTO.programid}';
                            j++;
            </c:forEach>
                        setPrograms(packagesEventIdArr);
                        //END

                        /* refill remaining collection list */
                        var packagesCollectionIdArr = new Array(${fn:length(packageDTO.collectionList)});
                        var k = 0;
                <c:forEach var="CollectionDTO" items="${packageDTO.collectionList}">
                            packagesCollectionIdArr[k] = '${CollectionDTO.collectionId}';
                            k++;
            </c:forEach>
                        setCollection(packagesCollectionIdArr);
                        //END
                        /* fill programs */
                        var x = document.getElementById('updateProgram');
                <c:forEach var="ProgramDTO" items="${packageDTO.programList}">
                            x.innerHTML += "<option value='${ProgramDTO.programid}'>${ProgramDTO.name}</option>";
            </c:forEach>
                        //END

                        /* fill channels */
                        var y = document.getElementById('updateChannel');
                <c:forEach var="SMSChannelDTO" items="${packageDTO.channelList}">
                            y.innerHTML += "<option value='${SMSChannelDTO.channelId}'>${SMSChannelDTO.name}</option>";
            </c:forEach>
                        //END

                        /* fill collection */
                        var z = document.getElementById('updateCollection');
                <c:forEach var="CollectionDTO" items="${packageDTO.collectionList}">
                            z.innerHTML += "<option value='${CollectionDTO.collectionId}'>${CollectionDTO.collectionName}</option>";
            </c:forEach>
                        //END

            <c:forEach var="DistributorDTO" items="${requestScope.displayDistributor}">
                 var allDistName=  '${DistributorDTO.email_id}';
                     <c:forEach var="DistributorDTO" items="${packageDTO.distributorListForPack}">
                            var packdist='${DistributorDTO.email_id}';
                            if(allDistName === packdist){
                              document.getElementById("prepaidprice"+packdist).value='${DistributorDTO.prepaidprice}';
                              document.getElementById("postpaidprice"+packdist).value='${DistributorDTO.postpaidprice}';
                             document.getElementById(packdist).checked = true;
                            }

                     </c:forEach>
             </c:forEach>
                        document.getElementById('updateDescription').value = "${packageDTO.description}";
                        document.getElementById('packImgName').value = '${packageDTO.image}';
                        document.getElementById('updatePackageImg1').style.display = 'inline';
                        document.getElementById('updatePrice').value = '${packageDTO.subscriptionPrice}';
                        document.getElementById('updateCurrency').value = '${packageDTO.priceUnit}';
                        document.getElementById('updateSubscriptionPeriod').value = '${packageDTO.subscriptionPeriod}';
                       var distributorType= '${packageDTO.distributorType}';
                        if(distributorType === "List distributors"){
                            document.getElementById('edit_pack_dist_dropdown').value ="List distributorsdisp";

                        }else{
                             document.getElementById('edit_pack_dist_dropdown').value = '${packageDTO.distributorType}';
                             }

                        document.getElementById('updatePostpaidPrice').value = '${packageDTO.updatePostpaidPrice}';
                        document.getElementById('updatePostPaidCurrency').value = '${packageDTO.updatePostPaidCurrency}';


                        document.getElementById('updateUnit').value = '${packageDTO.periodUnit}';
                        display('editPackDiv');
            <%-- document.getElementById('updateFeatured').checked = <c:if test="${packageDTO.featured == 1}">true</c:if><c:if test="${packageDTO.featured == 0}">false</c:if>;  --%>
                    } else if (packageId == '' || packageId == 'Select') {
                        document.getElementById('updatePackageName').value = '';
                        document.getElementById('packImgName').value = '';
                        document.getElementById('updatePackageImg1').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('updateDescription').value = '';
                        deselectChannelIds();
                        document.getElementById('packImg').src = '';
                        document.getElementById('updatePrice').value = '';
                        document.getElementById('updateCurrency').value = 'INR';
                        document.getElementById('updateSubscriptionPeriod').value = '';

                        document.getElementById('edit_pack_dist_dropdown').value =  '';

                        document.getElementById('updatePostpaidPrice').value =  '';
                        document.getElementById('updatePostPaidCurrency').value = '';

                        document.getElementById('updateUnit').value = 'day';
                        //document.getElementById('updateFeatured').checked = false;
                    }
        </c:forEach>
        return false;



          }
```

I get Uncaught ReferenceError: setPackage() is not defined error in chrome console.
Please do help me on this.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to use something that you have on your computer, online

Comment: @AllDani Thanks for your reply,if im trying to use something from my computer online then atleast it must give me alert which is the first line in my JS?Is it like not calling js itself? Correct me if im wrong please.

Comment: Wrong I think. The browser is not a validator. If it's done right, it'll work. Otherwise, it won't. The browser won't throw errors.

Comment: @AllDani Thanks friend.Im using dto to get value into html forms when i click on Edit tag.So is it like im trying to access data which is not available online?Or is it a problem before clicking Edit thing itself?

Comment: My guess? The first one.